# convert to objective c arc didn't do anything

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

In XCode 4.2 when I tried to `Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC ...` I got hundreds of errors after the conversion.  I used git to reset the code back to its former ARC-free self and it compiled fine.

I just tried again to `Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC ...` and it gave a preview of changes with exactly zero changes.  I have deallocs and releases all over my code and XCode says "Target currently uses ARC"

How can I make XCode 4.2 realize this project is *not* using ARC?

[image: screenshot of XCode claiming a file with a dealloc() is using ARC]

Comment: check the build settings on your project and see if xcode didnt add a flag that says something like noarc

Comment: @LuisOscar would you like to phrase your comment in the form of an Answer?  Are you in Tokyo?  maybe see you at next iOS meetup!

Comment: was that the problem? Honestly unless the file is super large its pretty easy to change to arc (just delete all retain, release, autoretain etc, xcode will mark them as errors anyway). Im in kyoto btw.

Comment: I added my answer but I figure yours is more helpful because it doesn't involve git.  Kyoto is a bit out of my normal hangouts haha

Answer (score 1):

I can't sure where goes wrong during your conversion, but I suggest you follow [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1) and see any differences about your steps.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by doing a git reset then Convert to ARC without selecting the problematic library.